# Getting error " emitted value instead of an instance of error while compiling template " while implement vue table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement a Vue table by using Vue table plugin in my application using node module. Here I am getting an error while using all Vue table component. Here I install all Vue table plugin using npm and import them in my custom component.

My snippet of code is attached here with.

```
import Vuetable from 'vuetable/src/components/Vuetable.vue';
import VuetablePagination from 'vuetable/src/components/VuetablePagination.vue';
import VuetablePaginationDropdown  from 'vuetable/src/components/VuetablePaginationDropdown.vue';
```

Here first I import the vue table plugin into my component.
Then register such component into my custom component into vue instance.

```
 data () { 
   return{
     columns: [
          'name',
          'nickname',
          'email',
          'birthdate',
          'gender',
          '__actions'
        ]
      }
    },
    components : {
        Vuetable,
        VuetablePagination,
        VuetablePaginationDropdown
    }
```

And in template section i write this block of code.

```
<vuetable
     api-url="http://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
     table-wrapper="#content"
     pagination-component="vuetable-pagination"
     :fields="columns">
</vuetable>
```

Comment: whats the actual error? did u try to open an issue in the repository ?

Answer (score 0):

first try to import vue and use component like sample below

```
import vue from 'vue';
vue.use(Vuetable);
vue.use(VuetablePagination);
vue.use(VuetablePaginationDropdown);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to debug each instance components html structure. You could be missing one of these:

- A closing tag arrow `>` or closing tag slash `/` in one of your elements.
- Absence of single root element.